# asp.net core 2.0 docker image for projects targeting full framework

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-framework-version

Microsoft has multiple docker image flavours for a different kind of .net projects. like

[.Net Framework](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet-framework/)

[Asp.Net](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnet/)

[.Net Core](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/)

[Asp.Net Core](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/)

Now I have project in asp.net core 2 targeting full net framework 4.6.1 (not targeting netcore2)

I want to use Docker for deployment of this project, where can I find a suitable docker image? asp.net core docker image only allows targeting .net core 2, not a full .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .NET Framework based docker images here. Since ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework images will contain everything that is needed in the published output, the app should run fine on just .NET Framework dependencies.

The docker image for ASP.NET Core on .NET Core only contains the runtime store for the requested ASP.NET Core version in addition to the .NET Core runtime so that the dependencies that aren't included in the published output and expected on the target machine are found.